# How can I implement a n intelliJ plugin action on a build.gradle file?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins, build.gradle

I am working on a plugin on intelliJ IDE and I want my action to be triggered on both java files and the build.gradle file. Right now I am unable to get the plugin action to work on the build.gradle file no matter what I try - it seems like the menu item for the action is disabled once I trigger it from the build.gradle file. However, it works once I am on a .java file.

How can I enable the action to work on the build.gradle file?

Answer (score 0):

Check the related IntelliJ Platform SDK documentation about an action [AnAction.update method](https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/action_system.html#overriding-the-anactionupdate-method):

> The `update()` method gives an action to evaluate the current context and enable or disable its functionality.
>
> The `enabled`/`disabled` state of an action is set using `Presentation.setEnabled()`. The visibility state of an action is set using `Presentation.setVisible()`.